# Как вывести атрибут над название товара woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

К вывести атрибут над название товара ?
у меня есть интернет магазина [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как мне сделать это ?
если через function php то посоветуйте что нибудь ? или есть какие то плагины ?

Answer (score 0):

> как мне сделать это ?

Нужно в дочерней теме изменить шаблон товара

Материалы для изучения:
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/